# Binary radix sort not working with unsigned char for bigger amounds of numbers

Tags: sorting

```
void Counting_Sort(vector<unsigned char>& A, unsigned int k)
{
    vector<unsigned char> C(2);
    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
        C[(A[i]>>k)&1]++;

    C[1] += C[0];

    vector<unsigned char> B(A.size());
    for (int i = A.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        B[--C[(A[i] >> k) & 1]] = A[i];
    }

    swap(A, B);
}

 void Binary_Radix_Sort(vector<unsigned char>& A)
 {
     for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
     {
         Counting_Sort(A, k);
     }
 }

 int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
 {
     vector<int> vec;
     //Reading from file, filling vector
     Binary_Radix_Sort(vec);
     //Output A
 }
```

If the vector A is small enough the sorting works fine, if there are more elements (I tried with 257) the sorted vector contains a bunch of zeroes at random places. If I change vector types from unsigned char to int then it works. All numbers that I'm sorting are between 0 and 255. It seems to break at about 255 so perhaps it has to do something with it, printing the vector before sorting is fine, but during sorting something breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the maximum value for `unsigned char` in your environment is 255.

Use proper larger integer type for the elements of the vector `C` (counter).

`size_t` should be a good type to use.